# SwiftUI View starter code complains about `inheritance from non-protocol type 'View'` when added to an existing project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I have an existing Xcode project. I need to create a new view. I was going to use File > New > File... > View, but then I noticed there is another option `SwiftUI View`. So I decided to give it a shot. I went ahead and chose SwiftUI View.

It created the following starter code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct FooBar: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
    }
}

struct FooBar_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        FooBar()
    }
}
```

And it has the following compiler errors:

> [image]

I tried cleaning, and selecting the iPhone 11 Pro simulator as the destination target, but it still has the same compiler errors.

For search-ability, here are all the errors:

> - Inheritance from non-protocol type 'View' (aka 'UIView')
> - Function declares an opaque return type, but has no return statements in its body from which to infer an underlying type
> - Cannot convert return expression of type 'Text' to return type 'some View'
> - Type 'FooBar_Previews' does not conform to protocol 'PreviewProvider'
> - Function declares an opaque return type, but has no return statements in its body from which to infer an underlying type
> - Cannot convert return expression of type 'FooBar' to return type 'some View'

I'm on macOS Catalina, Xcode 11.2.1, and the deployment target is iOS 13.0.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you quit Xcode or someWhere have defined `view` class?

Comment: Ahh I did indeed have a `typealias View = UIView` buried somewhere in the code. Could you please add that as an answer, @E.Coms?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems to us there is a `typealias View = UIView` some where to mess the `View` with `UIView`.

Comment: Or there could be a Struct View somewhere. It was in my case.